# Change Settings of a PDF document with PDFSharp

Tags: vb.net, pdf, pdfsharp

What I want to do is to send a PDF Document to a user and restrict him to do anything other than to scroll and zoom within the document. Especially the print option should be disabled. I tried it with the following VB.NET Code, creating a new PDF file:

```
Imports PdfSharp.Drawing
Dim document As New PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument

    document.Info.Title = "Built with PDFSharp"
    document.Info.CreationDate = Now
    document.Info.Subject = "PDFSharp Test"

    Dim page As PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage = document.AddPage

    Dim gfx As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page)
    Dim font As PdfSharp.Drawing.XFont = New PdfSharp.Drawing.XFont("Verdana", 20, PdfSharp.Drawing.XFontStyle.Bold)
    gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black, New XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height), XStringFormats.Center)

    document.SecuritySettings.PermitFullQualityPrint = False
    document.SecuritySettings.PermitPrint = False
    document.SecuritySettings.PermitAccessibilityExtractContent = False
    document.SecuritySettings.PermitAnnotations = False
    document.SecuritySettings.PermitAssembleDocument = False
    document.SecuritySettings.PermitExtractContent = False
    document.SecuritySettings.PermitFormsFill = False
    document.SecuritySettings.PermitModifyDocument = False

    ' Save the file
    Dim filename As String = "HelloWorld.pdf"
    document.Save(filename)
```

But when the PDF document is opened, there still is the possibility to print and to do other things, like it is in normal PDF documents. Am I missunderstanding the *securitySettings*? I view the PDF document with adobe acrobot. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't set an owner password, therefore anybody can do anything without password.

Set an owner password and Adobe Reader should prevent printing etc.

See also:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/ProtectDocument-sample.ashx

Do not set a user password if you want people to be able to view the document without entering a password.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a little bit late, but this helped me regarding this problem:

If you set an owner password, but no user password, then everybody can open the document using Adobe Reader without entering a password.
But a password is needed to make changes in Adobe Acrobat.
Watch it, but don't modify it.
ref. http://forum.pdfsharp.de/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1777